# How to design Dropdown List with text box to filter in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to place a Dropdown bound by a Dataset which may contain hundreds of items and user can type to filter and then select the item in it. I have tried many solution but I could not get what exactly I was looking for...
I want to get the exact same thing which is used at this website...please check the link http://www.pakwheels.com and advise...thanks

Answer (score 3):

you can use DropDown Chosen Dll which is so good..!! You use the below link..!!
download the source code..!! you just just need to use the tag prefix at the top of the page..!! and add the dll reference..!! [DropDownChosen](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/620313/Custom-ASP-NET-DropdownList-Control-Using-Chosen-j)

```
<%@ Register Assembly="DropDownChosen" 
Namespace="CustomDropDown" TagPrefix="cc1" %> 



<cc1:DropDownListChosen ID="DropDownListChosen1" runat="server" 
        NoResultsText="No results match." width="350px"            
        DataPlaceHolder="Type Here..." AllowSingleDeselect="true"  DisableSearchThreshold="1" >                
    </cc1:DropDownListChosen>
```